# Image get bigger on click on small image

Tags: android, image

I created an image(ImageView) on the application, I need to make the image bigger and able zoom once user click on the small image. I try pop up but it only show the image but not able zoom . Any idea how I can achieve it. Appreciate if can provide me some link where I can read on. Thanks.

Comment: you want to zoom image by touch?

Comment: @Shalini...yes..user can zoom it....by touch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used below code to do zoom in and zoom out for image view

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ZoomInZoomOut extends Activity implements OnTouchListener 
{
    private static final String TAG = "Touch";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f,MAX_ZOOM = 1f;

    // These matrices will be used to scale points of the image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        float scale;

        dumpEvent(event);
        // Handle touch events here...

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only
                                                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                                                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
                                                mode = DRAG;
                                                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

                                                mode = NONE;
                                                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                                                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down

                                                oldDist = spacing(event);
                                                Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                                                if (oldDist > 5f) {
                                                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                                    midPoint(mid, event);
                                                    mode = ZOOM;
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                                                }
                                                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                                                if (mode == DRAG) 
                                                { 
                                                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
                                                } 
                                                else if (mode == ZOOM) 
                                                { 
                                                    // pinch zooming
                                                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                                                    if (newDist > 5f) 
                                                    {
                                                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                        scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                                                                                    // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                                                                                    // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                                                                                    // zoom out
                                                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                break;
        }

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

        return true; // indicate event was handled
    }

    /*
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Method: spacing Parameters: MotionEvent Returns: float Description:
     * checks the spacing between the two fingers on touch
     * ----------------------------------------------------
     */

    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /*
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Method: midPoint Parameters: PointF object, MotionEvent Returns: void
     * Description: calculates the midpoint between the two fingers
     * ------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
    private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE","POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

        if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) 
        {
            sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
            sb.append(")");
        }

        sb.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) 
        {
            sb.append("#").append(i);
            sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
            sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
            sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
            if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                sb.append(";");
        }

        sb.append("]");
        Log.d("Touch Events ---------", sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to use this activity. It's perfect except one little thing : the first touch on the imageview make it go to the top left corner. After i can zoom etc but the first touch is bugged. Do you have any idea why ? Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

ImageView doesn't support by default the zoomable feature. You have to implement yourself, but  you can find some useful library in internet:

- http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/: I recommend you this, I was able to integrate with ViewPager.
- https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView
- https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview

As @Amal comments, there are good tutorials that explain the process step by step:

- http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/
- http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747

Comment: there is also [this tutorial](http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/) that explain custom ImageView step by step